# Trying to delete all li in an ul where the li id Greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to delete all `<li>` inside a `<ul>` where the `id` is greater  than a number.

It should remove the `<li>` with the id 6 to 4

```js
$('.row-fruit').filter(function (i) {
  return this.id > 3;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myFruits">
   <li class="row-fruit" id="1">mango</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="2">tomato</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="3">banana</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="4">watermelon</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="5">apple</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="6">lemon</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your code example works as is, you should convert the ID to a number from a string so that it will continue to work as expected for numbers with more than one digit.

```js
$('.row-fruit').filter(function(i) {

   return (parseInt(this.id, 10) > 3);

 }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myFruits">
   <li class="row-fruit" id="1">mango</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="2">tomato</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="3">banana</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="4">watermelon</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="5">apple</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="6">lemon</li>
  </ul>
```

Here I used `parseInt` to perform the conversion to number.

---

And here's a non-jQuery version:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.row-fruit'))
  .filter(el => parseInt(el.id, 10) > 3)
  .forEach(el => el.remove());
```

```html
<ul id="myFruits">
  <li class="row-fruit" id="1">mango</li>
  <li class="row-fruit" id="2">tomato</li>
  <li class="row-fruit" id="3">banana</li>
  <li class="row-fruit" id="4">watermelon</li>
  <li class="row-fruit" id="5">apple</li>
  <li class="row-fruit" id="6">lemon</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ziggy wiggy - Ok I will try that.. It worked but sometimes it doesn't I don't know why..

Answer (score 2):

An ID that starts with a number is generally not a very good idea, had you been using characters for ID's and just filtered with something like `gt()` instead, you wouldn't have this problem to begin with

```js
$('.row-fruit:gt(2)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myFruits">
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a1">mango</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a2">tomato</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a3">banana</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a4">watermelon</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a5">apple</li>
   <li class="row-fruit" id="a6">lemon</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I knew it was a bad idea to use just the number as id but it wasn't call...Supervisor ask me to.. . I will try to convince him again and we'll see how it goes.but thanks

Comment: Back in the day, before HTML5, the specification specifically said an ID couldn't start with a number, but in HTML5 it **can** start with a number, it's just never a very good idea.